# If one entices someone to sin (i.e mesit) are they liable to induce them to not commit the sin and/or follow the commands as part of repentance?

Tags: halacha, repentance-teshuvah

If someone was a mesit (i.e an enticer) and tried to influence someone to commit a sin, as part of that person's repentance, are they liable to track that person down and try and convince them not to sin? What about if the person didn't actually commit the sin? Is it different if the subject of the enticement was a jew or a non-jew?

Comment: Can you provide some examples, I think it largely depends on what the sin is and what kind of Teshuva it is.